# Is it morally okay to donate potentially tainted goods?

Tags: ethics

I am a computer person and have a bunch of USBs that could potentially have traces of network malware. The malware has not really done much to my work / daily routines but it has taught me that at some point I had network malware that could potentially travel over USB. I know nothing with complete certainty.

Anyway, to protect myself from possibly infecting computers when transferring files, I usually throw a used USB into a pile after its used.

I have a lot of fastish USB drives that I know people would like to have. My question is.. should I donate the USB drives even though they're possibly tainted with some malware that only I believe exists?

Comment: Why don't you just remove the malware and then donate them?

Comment: hey @prof because this is more or less a pastoral advice question, unless you add more context (which faith tradition) you're going to get some pretty generic answers/ advice which is why we don't allow these kinds of questions.  I'm sure there's a natural law reason and an application of the 10 commandments that would apply to this, but we try to avoid potentially contradictory answers so you we need to know where you're coming from and what kinds of answers you'd accept

Answer (score 2):

There is a relatively simple test that you can do to give you a good indication of the morality, based on the teachings of Jesus. Ask yourself "Would I want someone to give me one of these, and would I use it If they did?" You can also tell the recipient what the problem with the drive is when you give it to them, then they can make their own decision.

Comment: Yes, providing that you have warned them about the potential problems and they are capable of understanding, "*they can make their own decision*" is almost always the right answer.  Always assuming the responsibility of protecting other people is a good way of making them even more vulnerable to those other people that lack your morals.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with @DJClayworth and @RayButterworth that disclosing your concern plus saying "use at your own risk" should be sufficient to relieve your conscience.

For extra precaution:

1. I would only give them to people who *can* understand and appreciate the warning.  Thus, not to someone who doesn't even know what "USB" or "rootkit" means.
2. I would also only give them to someone who (based on my reasonable knowledge of the person) would take the right precaution, not someone whom I know to be reckless.

Other alternatives:

1. Use a tool such as [USB Low-Level Format](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/usb_low_level_format.html) installed on a bootable CD, on a stand-alone computer (not connected to any network) without any hard drives / SSD.
2. Ask a security conscious IT colleague who do these kinds of things in their job to wipe clean those USB drives.
3. Donate / sell them to a computer repair shop.

Answer (score 0):

## Consider giving them to an e-waste facility rather than throwing them away.

God gave humanity stewardship over the Earth, and part of that would involve the responsible and sustainable use of resources. Since electronics use certain rare minerals in their production, and mining them can cause a fair bit of environmental damage, rather than throwing them away, I would consider giving them to an e-waste handling facility to be recycled.